# Change html video control source at runtime

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to update the html video control located on my page with a new source, here is my code which runs through 4 controls with the ids video01, video02.. video04 and should populate the sources of them with the video files found in the directory fileDir.

```
String[] videoFiles = Directory.GetFiles(fileDir);
    int i = 0;
    HtmlVideo vid;
    foreach (string f in videoFiles)
    {
        i++;
        vid = (HtmlVideo)FindControl("video0" + i.ToString());
        vid.Src = "f";

    }
```

while on the aspx page I have 4 controls of this kind

```
<div style="width:100%; height:330px">
    <div style="width:330px; float:left; height:321px; border:thick; border: thick none black;">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_vid1">Slave 01 - No input</asp:Label>
        <video runat="server" id="video01" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
          <source src="yourmovie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
```

The code does not work.

Comment: define "does not work".  what **does** it do?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your code read:

```
String[] videoFiles = Directory.GetFiles(fileDir);
    int i = 0;
    HtmlVideo vid;
    foreach (string f in videoFiles)
    {
        i++;
        vid = (HtmlVideo)FindControl("video0" + i.ToString());
        vid.Src = f;

    }
```

"f" indicates that the source is a url "f".
You need `f` which contains the source.

If this is not the issue, look to see if your c# code can actually find the control.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the spare quote chars, but now the code just adds another tag to the video control which called "video src" where it puts the correct path to the file while the path should be inserted into the existing "source src" tag.

Comment: Does this update the video source as required? If so, you can add an ID to the `<source>` tag and do the same as you did for the `video>` tag